# Streamlit IFC.js viewer component not working

Tags: javascript, python, windows, streamlit, ifc-open-shell

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/myoualid/ifc-101-course/tree/main) in an attempt to create a streamlit IFC data app.

The problem is that the IFC visualizer component is not working and i have no idea what the issue is.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWJsE.png)
Error text:

```
Your app is having trouble loading the __Viewer.ifc_js_viewer component.

(The app is attempting to load the component from ****, and hasn't received its "streamlit
" message.)

If this is a development build, have you started the dev server?
If this is a release build, have you compiled the frontend?
For more troubleshooting help, please see the Streamlit Component docs or visit our forums.
```

I have tried both following the tutorial and cloning the repo as is but the error persists.
I dont know if this is an environment issue but i belive it is.
Here is my env:

- Streamlit version 1.28.2
- Python 3.10.13 (anaconda 3)
- ifcopenshell  0.7.0.231127
- windows 11
- tested on chrome+brave

if someone could clone the repo and see if the problem is there I would be very thankful.
This is my first time working with js and streamlit

I also tried running it on my laptop with a similar env and the bug still persists.